# Cannot deploy an app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an application to Heroku, but after deployment in the logs I get the following error:

```
2017-08-09T09:32:39.071603+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876049+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.js:38
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876059+00:00 app[web.1]: app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876060+00:00 app[web.1]:                             ^
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876063+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'PORT' of undefined
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:38:29)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876064+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876068+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-08-09T09:32:39.876071+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

I get the same error when I try to run the application locally

```
11:26:03 web.1   |  var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
11:26:03 web.1   |                        ^
11:26:03 web.1   |  TypeError: Cannot read property 'PORT' of undefined
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you change `process.env` somewhere in code ?

Comment: nope. This is the only time I am accessing process.env:

`var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));`

Comment: Problem SOLVED!!! In the code, I had a function named process. So I was redefining this which was breaking the default behaviour.  After changing the name of the function, everything works like a charm.

Comment: It's a known error.